# Can't unpickle GeoAlchemy GeometryColumn. Possible solution: 2 sqlalchemy models for same table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some sqlalchemy models that has a GeometryColumn.
For my caching purposes i use cPickle.
Now, while this column is empty everything fine. However, if it has data I receive:

```
TypeError: buffer() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

while doing `cPickle.loads(data)`

I dont really need this column in this query, i will be happy to exclude it.
But doing something like `mymodel.geom = None` before pickling still give this error

The only solution i get in mind is to define another sqlalchemy model, that will not have this column. But if i set:

`__tablename__ = 'same_table'`

I receive:

```
Table 'my_model' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

Is there any solution for any of this errors or some getaround?
btw trying to do something like:

```
class MyModelNoGeom(MyModel):
   __tablename__=MyModel.__tablename__
   __table__.extend_existing=True

   geom=None
```

Also gives error:

`NameError: name '__table__' is not defined`

Comment: Oh, found some way to do it, a bit weird, but works

Before sending collection of objects into cache i do following:

    temp_geom=MyModel.geom
    MyModel.geom=None
    send_to_cache()
    MyMyodel.geom=temp_geom

But i hope someone can think about better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single solution I found:
A bit ugly, but works.

```
temp_geom=MyModel.geom
MyModel.geom=None 
objects_MyModel.send_to_cache() 
MyMyodel.geom=temp_geom
```

Comment: I've encountered the same issue under a different context. This is caused when pickling a binary field due to a bug in the python 2.7 pickle module. Perhaps my solution can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609909/pickling-a-django-model-with-a-binary-field-in-cacheops/24670523#24670523